# How to convert query sql to shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a shortcode like this [myshorcode:2:drinks], and query-wrangler I have managed to get the following query that shows me 2 products of a certain taxonomy

PHP WP_Query:

```
$query = array (
  'paged' => 1,
  'posts_per_page' => '2',
  'offset' => 0,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'tax_query' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'taxonomy' => 'product_brand',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => 
      array (
        0 => 30,
      ),
      'operator' => 'IN',
      'include_children' => false,
    ),
  ),
  'post_type' => 
  array (
    'product' => 'product',
  ),
);
```

This query works well but doesn't give me the option to put the name of the taxonomy, just the id.

That's why I would like to make a shortcode where I put [product:2:name-taxonomy] or [product:name-taxonomy], and the 2 I leave it fixed.

Thank you for your opinions and help.

Answer (score 0):

According to standard method in WordPress, Shortcode attributes are entered like this:

```
[productlist no_of_products="2" producttax="name-taxonomy"]
```

Following is the code for Shortcode function:

```
function productlist_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'no_of_products' => '2',
        'producttax' => 'name-taxonomy',
    ), $atts );

    //write Query logic here
}
add_shortcode( 'productlist', 'productlist_func' );
```

Attributes will be converted into an associative array like the following, passed to the handler function as its $atts parameter:

```
array( 'no_of_products' => '2', 'producttax' => 'name-taxonomy' )
```

[check Shortcode API on WordPress Codex for more details.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)